# How to build a bootstrap form validation?

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have been trying to create a form validated for my call-back form (Full name and Phone number only), but does not work. please can you help me how to update the JavaScript check the valid INPUT information?

I want the valid Full name format such as "First Name Last Name" and UK phone number format as the valid information, the valid fields turn green (with a tickmark), thereby giving immediate feedback to users. please see my code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head> 
    
<body>

<form method="post" action="php/call-back.php">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                                <input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your Full Name" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                                <input id="phone" type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone number" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                                <input type="hidden" name="save" value="contact">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default pull-right">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
  
 <!-- JavaScript -->
 <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You mentioned _"does not work"_ . Where are your validation scripts ?

Comment: Check out the below link. There are some examples that will help you. I have used this previously for similar validation and it worked.   [link](http://formvalidation.io/examples/validating-field-special-name/)

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I have not created a scripts for it yet, I have tried to use lot of similar validation but wasn't work. If you was me, how do you update it?

Comment: You could use a library like [bootstrap-validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/). You should also refer to the Bootstrap documentation for forms, there are examples of how to show feedback icons there.